# PHP wordwrap not working on <select> tag

Tags: php, word-wrap

```
while ($desc = $db->fetch_assoc()):
   $str =  $desc['description'] . '<br>';
   $fstr =  wordwrap($str, 50, '<br>\n');

   $desc1 .= "<option>" . $fstr ." </option>";

endwhile;

<select id="classtype">
            <?php echo  $desc1; ?>
</select>
```

Is `wordwrap` not applicable for `<select>`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php was `"<br />\n");` with double quotes. Doubt if it makes a difference. *Just saying*

Comment: try $fStr= wordwrap($str, 50, "<br />", true);

Comment: As mentioned in the other SO question linked, the problem is that browsers don't allow you to add line breaks to options in select lists. This is not a problem with your PHP script per se, it's how browsers themselves behave.

Comment: Even if line breaks were allowed, it would have to be with `<br>`, because newlines in HTML are treated like spaces except in `<pre>` blocks. PHP's `nl2br()` function is helpful there.

Comment: Maybe if your content is so long that you have to break a select is the wrong ui element.